# How to make commit from changes to copy of the file?

Tags: git, diff, tortoisegit

For legacy reason, my "development environment" consists of copy of original file.

How can I instruct **git/tortoise** now, to treat that copy as changes to original file?

(Just copying the changes is no-go because, not all changes should be applied, so copying + making partial commit + reverting to newer version, would take too much time, while done on live production system)

Comment: So you develop directly on production? And to change a file, you copy just that file, change it, then copy it back?

Comment: Also, if you do not want to apply all changes you made, why do you want to check in all changes? Why not undo the "bad" changes first? Please add some details about your (apparently fairly unusual) development setup. For example: Where is your working copy checked out? Do you use branches?

Comment: I don't think there is anything ready which would require no action from user, but you could use `git merge-file` to move the changes from one file to another.

Comment: @sleske "Legacy reasons"... Belive me that I like those arrangements less then You. But I'm "junior" programmer on the team. Please focus on the question. And do note text in brackets, I know that copy-paste is not the answer.

Comment: @przemo_li: My questions do focus on your question, I believe. I just don't understand your workflow. In particular, why you want to check in changes, even though you don't want to apply them in production.

Comment: Oh. I do want them on production. Just do not want to merge those two files by hand on production.

Comment: Ok. I could make patch between the two. Edit it. Apply only required changes to original file. Commit original file. Or maybe there is the-git-way TM for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, this setup makes it really hard to work, and is not the way git is expected to be used.

That said, if it has to work like this, one solution would be to have a second working copy for development (using either [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) or an additional clone). In that working copy, you check out the commit you want your changes to be based on. Then you copy over the modified file, and commit it. If necessary, you can split the changes across multiple commits, e.g. using `git add -i`.

Now you have converted your changes into one or more git commits, which you can merge or cherry-pick into the production branch or production repository, in order to check them out into production (I assume you use git as your deployment tool).